# Custom InstallSchema script for updated_at default column: as_defined

Tags: magento2, database

How to write the below using Install Scheme script .

I want initially the updated_at to be 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tgs_queue` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID',
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
 )
```

Is the below rite?

```
->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [ 'nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT, ],
            'Created At'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [ 'nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE, ],
            'Updated At'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->addColumn(
        'updated_at',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
        'Updated At'
```

`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Updated At'

Comment: I want updated_at columns default value to be 'as defined' by 00 :00 as shown

Comment: Make changes as per you need ALTER TABLE  `customer_entity` CHANGE  `created_at`  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT  'Created At';
ALTER TABLE  `customer_entity` CHANGE  `updated_at`  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT  'Updated At';   for ref https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/correct-created_at-and-updated_at-columns-issue/